# Replicas created on same node before being transferred

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch cluster made up of 3 nodes.

Every day, I have a batch that feeds in a new index composed of 3 shards then scales the number of replicas to 1. So at the end of the day I'm expecting every node to carry 1 primary and 1 replica.

The figure below shows the disk space usage on each node during this operation.

[image: Evolution of disk space when scaling up replicas]

On `node 0` everything seems to be going smoothly during that operation.

However, `node 2` is idle most of the time at the beginning while `node 1` seems to be is taking care of its own replica plus `node 2` replica, before transferring it to `node 2` (this is my own understanding, I might be wrong). This is causing a lot of pressure on the disk usage of `node 1` which almost reaches 100% of disk space usage.

Why this behaviour? Shouldn't every node take care of its own replica here to even the load? Can I force it to do so somehow? This is worrying because when a disk reaches 100%, the entire node goes down as it happened in the past.

**UPDATE to Val's answer:**

You will find the outputs below

**GET _cat/shards/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20210617?v**

```
index                           shard prirep state      docs  store ip            node
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20210617 1     p      STARTED 8925915 13.4gb 172.23.13.255 es-master-0
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20210617 1     r      STARTED 8925915 13.4gb 172.23.10.76  es-master-2
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20210617 2     r      STARTED 8920172 13.4gb 172.23.24.221 es-master-1
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20210617 2     p      STARTED 8920172 13.4gb 172.23.10.76  es-master-2
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20210617 0     p      STARTED 8923889 13.4gb 172.23.24.221 es-master-1
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20210617 0     r      STARTED 8923889 13.5gb 172.23.13.255 es-master-0
```

**GET _cat/recovery/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20210617?v**

```
index                           shard time  type        stage source_host   source_node            target_host   target_node            repository snapshot files files_recovered files_percent files_total bytes       bytes_recovered bytes_percent bytes_total translog_ops translog_ops_recovered translog_ops_percent
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20210617  0     382ms empty_store done  n/a           n/a                    172.23.24.221 es-master-1            n/a        n/a      0     0               0.0%          0           0           0               0.0%          0           0            0                      100.0%
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20210617  0     21.9m peer        done  172.23.24.221 es-master-1            172.23.13.255 es-master-0            n/a        n/a      188   188             100.0%        188         14467579393 14467579393     100.0%        14467579393 55835        55835                  100.0%
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20210617  1     395ms empty_store done  n/a           n/a                    172.23.13.255 es-master-0            n/a        n/a      0     0               0.0%          0           0           0               0.0%          0           0            0                      100.0%
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20210617  1     9m    peer        done  172.23.13.255 es-master-0            172.23.10.76  es-master-2            n/a        n/a      188   188             100.0%        188         14486949488 14486949488     100.0%        14486949488 0            0                      100.0%
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20210617  2     17.8m peer        done  172.23.10.76  es-master-2            172.23.24.221 es-master-1            n/a        n/a      134   134             100.0%        134         14470475298 14470475298     100.0%        14470475298 1894         1894                   100.0%
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20210617  2     409ms empty_store done  n/a           n/a                    172.23.10.76  es-master-2            n/a        n/a      0     0               0.0%          0           0           0               0.0%          0           0            0                      100.0%
```

Comment: Can you explain if the index is created with or without replicas at first? When you say "then scales the number of replicas to 1" where does it happen on the chart you've shared? Also can you explain the dip at the beginning? Is it because you're deleting the old index first?

Comment: No the index is created with no replicas at first. At the beginning of the chart, the new index has already been indexed, I only show the next parts : scaling down of older index (the dip that you mentioned)  then the scale up of the new created index. On the chart that starts at 22:54.

Comment: So, just to make sure: first you index the new index with only primaries. When that's done, you remove the replicas of the old index and add replicas to the new index? Is that right? Side question: Why don't you delete the old index altogether?

Comment: Yes exactly. We actually delete the index when it becomes 2 days old (part not showed on the screen). When keep the index of yesterday just in case we need to rollback to it.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have 3 nodes and your index has 3 primaries with each having 1 replica, there's absolutely no guarantee whatsoever that each node will hold one primary and one replica.

The only guarantees that you have is that:

1. the shard count will be balanced over the nodes and
2. a primary and its replica will never land on the same node.

That being said, it's perfectly possible for a node to get two primaries, another two replicas and the 3rd one gets one primary and one replica.

Looking at the chart, what I think happens in your case is that

- node 2 gets two primaries and
- node 0 gets one primary

Then, when you add the replica:

- node 0 (which has only one primary) gets one replica (the curve is less steep)
- node 1 (which has nothing so far) gets two replicas (the curve grows steeper)
- node 2 stays flat because it already has two primaries

A little later, when node 1's disk approaches saturation, one shard is relocated away from it to node 2 (at 23:16 the curve starts to increase).

The end situation seems to be:

- node 0 with one primary and one replica
- node 1 with only one replica
- node 2 with two primaries and one replica

I think it would be nice to confirm this with the following two commands:

```
# you can see where each shard is located now
GET _cat/shards/tax*?v

# you can see which shards went from which node to which node
GET _cat/recovery/indexname*?v
```

Comment: I have updated my answer by adding the outputs of both commands. I know that ES offer no guarantees about primaries distribution but since it does keep shards count balanced across nodes, am I not guaranteed that my primaries will end on different nodes provided that the initial count of shards is evenly distributed? Anyway looking by the ouputs,  it looks like primaries and replicas are evenly distributed in the end. Thank you for your help.